# GetBase API return translation missing: en-US.activerecord.errors.models.deal.attributes.base.upgrade_required

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, api, activerecord, internationalization

I am working with [Base Api](https://developers.getbase.com/docs/rest/reference/deals) with oAuth 2.0 authentication. As per the API, I need to POST json data to create anything through the api. Things working fine. I can get/create contacts as per their documentation. But when I want to create a Deal  *Ref: [Deal Api Doc](https://developers.getbase.com/docs/rest/reference/deals)*, I am getting some error.

Error

```
{
      "meta": {
        "http_status": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
        "type": "errors",
        "logref": "aech0-3arq9-kgulg-4sd10",
        "links": {
          "more_info": "https://developers.getbase.com/docs/rest/articles/errors"
        }
      },
      "errors": [
        {
          "error": {
            "resource": "deal",
            "code": "domain_error",
            "message": "translation missing: en-US.activerecord.errors.models.deal.attributes.base.upgrade_required"
          },
          "meta": {
            "links": {
              "more_info": "https://developers.getbase.com/docs/rest/articles/errors"
            },
            "type": "error"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Data I am trying to POST is:

```
{"data":{"name":"VTB Test Deal","value":5,"contact_id":26857049,
        "custom_fields":{"website":"http:\/\/vtb.dev"}},
        "meta":{"type":"deal"}}
```

Unfortunately there is nothing in their documentation about this error. I tried to search about this error, only clue I got is, it might be related with RubyOnRails and Internationalization.

The app I am working is based on Laravel 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in Base API, we have already fixed it. It should return a correct error message now.

Seems your Base account is on a Free plan. This plan has a 50 deals limit. You need to upgrade your account to a paid plan, to remove the limit. Please contact support@getbase.com if you have any questions regarding the API or upgrade.

Disclaimer: I'm a Base employee.

Comment: Thanks for clarify. I already contacted to support but after contacting to support, I figured out that I can't add any deal from the app also and its actually due to free account. I contacted to my client and once he purchase subscription, I'll restart my work there. Thanks for your answer :) @Marcin Biegun